# Test ansible roles with molecule and vagrant

Tags: ansible, vagrant, devops, molecule

I would test my ansible role with molecule and vagrant in local before commit my code. But, my OS machine is windows not linux.
What is the best way to accomplish my obejective?
Could describe me the steps, please?

Comment: Install Ansible in WSL in order to use Ansible on Windows. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#control-node-requirements

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to test for different OS flavors, I would not use [Molecule vagrant plugin](https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule-vagrant).

Instead I would use [Rancher Desktop](https://rancherdesktop.io/) + [Molecule docker plugin](https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule-docker), so your molecule tests run inside containers.

Steps:

1. Install Rancher Desktop (which also configures WSL)
2. Install ansible and molecule on WSL
3. Configure your roles / playbooks with the molecule-docker [example](https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule-docker/blob/main/molecule/default/molecule.yml)
4. Use molecule normally

Answer (score 0):

For a fully working example of Molecule + virtualbox you can look here https://hashiqube.com/ansible/README I needed to test Ansible Roles and Playbooks for Windows 2019 / 2016 Ubuntu 22.04 / 20.04 Redhat linux 7 / 8 Centos 7 / 8 - I had to test this on Windows WSL / Linux Ubuntu and Mac Intel (I was not able to get Mac Arm chipset workin)

Good luck, Molecule and Ansible is incredibly powerful!